# How to get Prefab size before Instantiating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Prefab made of an **Image** element and a **Text** element in the Image. Depending on the length of the text, the prefab gets wider or taller.
In script, I need to change the text and get the new size (height, width) of the prefab BEFORE using Instantiate(prefab). My problem is that I'm always getting a size of 0, or the size of the original prefab, without the text modification.
My script looks like that :

```
prefab.GetComponent<Text>().text = myNewText; //insert a long text, supposed to make the prefab wider
float newSize = prefab.GetComponent<Image>().preferredWidth // always getting 0 or the original width of the prefab

// do some things with newSize

Instantiate(prefab);
```

PS : There is no Collider or mesh renderer in my prefab.

I also tried `.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta` or `.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.size.y` but I always get 0 or the size of the original prefab, without the longer text.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The answer is you can't, however as soon as you instantiate and set the text you can then get the width. As it's all done in the same frame before being rendered (remember, drawing to the screen is one of the last things that happens in the game loop) the user will not notice any change. So, instantiate then `// do some things with newSize`.

Comment: @Absinthe I get that but i need to `// do some things with newSize` before the prefab is visible... So i tried to Instantiate() an inactive prefab but it seems like it needs to be visible at least one frame to get the width of it...

Comment: A frame is not visible until the end of the game loop iteration. So, when you call `Instantiate` in `Update` for instance you can do any processing you need in `Update` and by the end of the frame (i.e. the end of your code in `Update`) you can do any amount of processing. Just because you instantiate something it doesn't mean the user will see that before your code has run. Does that make sense? The instantiated item will only be visible at the end of the frame, after any code you apply to it. Bear in mind you're probably rendering several hundred FPS in a simple scene with a modern GPU.

Comment: If I've misunderstood your point and you're finding you can't get the correct properties after instantiating in the same frame then immediately set the gameobject.active to false and use a coroutine to delay one frame, then do the processing and set active again.

Comment: @Absinthe god thanks that one worked for me ! Instantiate()>editing text > setting inactive > start a coroutine (wait end of frame > get correct properties) > setting active. Not sure I understand well why thats working but anyway.

Comment: Cool. I think Unity is set to prioritise render FPS over code logic so giving it a frame to process makes sense, given `Instantiate` is known to be a performance hog. You could consider object pooling instead: https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-object-pooling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that you will have to wait until the UI has done a refresh so all layout groups etc are up-to-date.

By default

> A canvas performs its layout and content generation calculations at the end of a frame, just before rendering, in order to ensure that it's based on all the latest changes that may have happened during that frame.

If you do not want to wait a frame what you will need to use is [`Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases.html)

```
var newInstance = Instantiate(prefab); 
newInstance.GetComponent<Text>().text = myNewText;

Canvas.ForceUpdateCanvases();
Debug.Log(newInstance.GetComponent<Text>().preferredWidth);
```

This can of course be expensive though depending on the complexity and amount of Canvases you have.

---

If you rather want to wait a frame you would need to use a coroutine and do

```
    StartCoroutine(SpawnRoutine());

...

private IEnuemrator SpawnRoutine()
{
    var newInstance = Instantiate(prefab); 
    newInstance.GetComponent<Text>().text = myNewText;

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    Debug.Log(newInstance.GetComponent<Text>().preferredWidth);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your first solution worked. Not the second one, idk why, I've read somewhere that properties of inactive objects are not updated. Anyway I guess that's better and cleaner to just force update the canvas than dealing with frames. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this would be: Instantiate the prefab, Set it as inactive in the scene, get the size, modify it as you like, then set it active again. It should look something like this

```
Gameobject newPrefab = Instantiate(prefab);
newPrefab.SetActive(false);
float newSize = newPrefab.GetComponent<Image>().preferredWidth;
DoStuff();
newPrefab.SetActive(true);
```

Have not tested this, but I think this is why you are not getting a width before instantiating

Comment: i was also thinking about this. but i just tried and this does'nt seem to work aswell... Instantiate>Modifiy Text>Set Inactive>Get width => gives me 0. Instantiate>Modifiy Text>Wait a frame>Set Inactive>Get width => gives me the width... but i can see the prefab one frame so...

Comment: What if tou instantiate, disable it, and and then after waiting for a frame you get the width. The object should be in the hierarchy so the information will still be available

Comment: Yes that's what worked (see other answers) ! thanks for helping aswell